# Decrease "position" property with Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

With this object:

```
const state = {
  a: {position: 1},
  b: {position: 2},
  c: {position: 3},
  d: {position: 4},
  e: {position: 5},
}
```

I'd like to remove the `b` object and then decrease the `position` by 1 from objects with a higher position (so just to `c`, `d` and `e`). The resulting state should be:

```
{
  a: {position: 1},
  c: {position: 2},
  d: {position: 3},
  e: {position: 4},
}
```

After having some fun with Ramda, I ended up with something like this:

```
const removeElement = (state, elementId) => {
  const newState = dissoc('b', state)

  return pipe(
    filter((currentDoc) => currentDoc.position > state[elementId].position),
    clone,
    forEachObjIndexed((value, key) => (value.position-=1), __),
    merge(newState) 
  )(newState)
}

removeElement(state, 'b')
```

It works, but I'm not completely happy with it because I find it a bit verbose. Do you think there is a nicer way to write it?

Comment: You should use `Map` instead where the position could be implicitly encoded by insertion order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

```js
const {dissoc, map} = R

const reshape = (state, key, pos = state[key].position) => dissoc(key, map(
  ({position}) => position > pos ? {position: position - 1} : {position},
  state
))

const state = { a: { position: 1 }, b: { position: 2 }, c: { position: 3 }, d: { position: 4 }, e: { position: 5 }, };

console.log(reshape(state, 'b'))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Note that the discussion between Nina and customcommander about *remove* is relevant here.  This version does not alter your original.  Ramda makes it a point never to do so.

If your state values are more than simply `{position: ?}`, then this version should do the trick:

```
const reshape = (state, key, pos = state[key].position) => dissoc(key, map(
  ({position, ...rest}) => position > pos 
    ? {position: position - 1, ...rest} 
    : {position, ...rest},
  state
))
```

Or, as Emi points out, this version is likely to be more performant:

```
const reshape = (state, key, pos = state[key].position) => dissoc(key, map(
  (obj) => obj.position > pos ? {...obj, position: obj.position - 1} : obj,
  state
))
```

Comment: Would not be more performant returning the same object reference than spreading it with {position, ...rest}? Like: (obj) => obj.position > pos ? {...obj, position: position - 1} : obj

Answer (score 0):

Just filter and update. Then delete.

```js
const state = { b: { position: 2 }, c: { position: 3 }, d: { position: 4 }, e: { position: 5 }, a: { position: 1 } };

Object
    .values(state)
    .filter(o => o.position > state.b.position)
    .forEach(o => o.position--);

delete state.b;

console.log(state);
```

Comment: I downvoted this solution as it tampers with the original object rather than creating a new one.

Comment: True but I suppose that doesn't necessarily mean that you have to remove it from the original object. As you can see in the OP initial attempt, the use of `clone` suggests that the OP didn't want to tamper the original object.

Answer (score 0):

A ramda solution that uses [lenses](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lens):

```js
const { pipe, dissoc, lensProp, map, over, dec, gt, view, when, flip, prop } = R

const pLens = lensProp('position');

const removeElement = (state, elementId) => pipe(
  dissoc(elementId),
  map(when(
    pipe(
      view(pLens), 
      flip(gt)(view(pLens, prop(elementId, state))
    )), 
    over(pLens, dec)
  ))
)(state)

const state = {"a":{"position":1},"b":{"position":2},"c":{"position":3},"d":{"position":4},"e":{"position":5}}

const result = removeElement(state, 'b')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split things a little bit:

Firstly a function that returns a function that checks if a `{position}` object has a `position` property lower than given number:

```
const positionLowerThan = (num) => propSatisfies(lt(num), 'position');
```

Secondly, a function that will take a `{position}` object and will simply decrease its `position` property:

```
const decreasePosition = over(lensProp('position'), dec);
```

Putting everything together:

```js
const {propSatisfies, over, lensProp, dec, pipe, omit, map, when, lt} = R;

const positionLowerThan = (num) => propSatisfies(lt(num), 'position');
const decreasePosition = over(lensProp('position'), dec);

const execute = (key, obj) =>
  pipe(omit([key]), map(when(positionLowerThan(obj[key].position), decreasePosition)))
    (obj);

console.log(

  execute('b', {
    a: {position: 1},
    b: {position: 2},
    c: {position: 3},
    d: {position: 4},
    e: {position: 5},
  })

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```